# Vistas en mysql de 2 campos con misma para una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, vistas

Tengo una tabla con 2 columnas con el mismo `id` de otra tabla, la estructura es la siguiente:
Tabla créditos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`idCliente` e `idAsociado` hacen referencia al id de la tabla clientes,pero en algunos campos los id son diferentes, deseo hacer una vista donde en lugar de los id's me muestre los nombres correspondientes a esos `id's`

Intente así:

```
CREATE VIEW creditosactivos (Folio,Nombre,Monto,FechaOtorgacion,FechaInicio,FechaFin,Cuota,Recuperado,Asociado)
 AS SELECT 
cr.idCreditos, cl.Nombre, cr.Monto, cr.FechaOtorgacion, cr.FechaInicio, cr.FechaFin, cr.cuota, cr.Recuperado, cl.Nombre
FROM creditos cr
INNER JOIN clientes cl
ON  cr.idCliente=cl.idClientes
WHERE cr.Estado='ACTIVO';
```

pero me repite los nombre de la columna `idCliente`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que tenés es que estás listando la misma columan dos veces.
En realidad necesitas dos relaciones separadas a la misma tabla.
Una forma de hacerlo es esta:

```
CREATE VIEW creditosactivos (Folio,Nombre,Monto,FechaOtorgacion,FechaInicio,FechaFin,Cuota,Recuperado,Asociado)
 AS SELECT 
    cr.idCreditos, 
    (select cl.Nombre from clientes cl where cl.idCliente = cr.idCliente) Cliente,
    cr.Monto, 
    cr.FechaOtorgacion, 
    cr.FechaInicio, 
    cr.FechaFin, 
    cr.cuota, 
    cr.Recuperado, 
    cr.idAsociado,
    (select asoc.Nombre from clientes asoc where asoc.idCliente = cr.idAsociado) Asociado,
FROM creditos cr
WHERE cr.Estado='ACTIVO';
```

Si lo querés hacer con joins tenes que joinear la tabla dos veces con clientes con diferente alias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, seguí la recomendación de los joins, de verdad muchas gracias!!